# real analysis, measure theory about a sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

suppose $\{E_n\}_n$ is a sequence of measurable sets, $J$ is a positive integer, $G$ is the set which contains the points that at least belong to $J$s $E_n$, i.e.

$$G= \{ x : \exists n_1 < \dots < n_J | x \in E_{n_1} \cap \dots \cap E_{n_J}\}$$
Prove that $G$ is measurable and $m(G)\le \frac{\sum m(E_n)}{J}$

I had proof the first part by defining $f_n(x)=X_{E_n}(x)$(characteristic function of $E_n$),and $G= \{x: \sum f_n(x) \ge J \}$
but the second part is hard to prove.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "at least belong to $J's E_n$

Comment: Use $$J\cdot\chi_G\leqslant\sum_n\chi_{E_n}$$

Comment: @tattwamasi amrutam  that means that the points in G at least belong to J sets(En).

Comment: @Did I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that: $$G:=\{x\in X\mid |\{n\mid x\in E_n\}|\geq J\}$$ Observe that:  $$1_G(x)=1\iff x\in G\iff\sum 1_{E_n}(x)\geq J$$This can also be expressed by$$J1_G(x)\leq\sum 1_{E_n}(x)$$

On both sides take integrals to arrive at:$$Jm(G)\leq\sum\mu(E_n)$$